# How to represent a unit as a point in pharo?

Tags: oop, dictionary, smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to program a game in Pharo. I have just started to code in Pharo, so I am trying to get used to it.

The game should include a game map and each character(or thing) is represented by a symbol.

The very first thing I did was to create a GameMapClass which contains a GameMap object.

Then I drew the map, which was easy.

The next thing to do is to put units. I have a Unit class(and some other classes that inherit the Unit class). I also have a unitAt method in my GameMapClass which is so far like this:

`unitAt: aPoint
    |thePoint|
    ^thePoint := map at: aPoint ifAbsent: [self error: 'The space is empty'].`

I don't know how to proceed in this method. The point should also returns the unit if it is not empty. How do I return for multiple times? Each point is aPointin my program. I also need to use dictionary to represent "things" with symbols and I have no idea about where to put this dictionary and how to access to it.

Comment: What are you asking about? Because I don't see any way that I can answer you question. I don't know if you want to return several objects or use several return statement, and for what reason. Also I don't understand the case with dictionary. I mean: you have added map to your class and are accessing it, what is a problem to do the same with dictionary. Please refine you question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
unitAt: aPoint
    | theUnit |
    theUnit := map 
        at: aPoint
        ifAbsent: [ self error: 'The space is empty' ].
    ^ { theUnit. aPoint }
```

Please consider @Uko's comment though: you pass in the point in this manner:

```
 unitAndPoint := myObject unitAt: myPoint.
```

If you look at this carefully you'll see that the variable `unitAndPoint` contains the same point object `myPoint` that you are passing as an argument. That means you already know the point and there is *no reason* for you to return it from `unitAt:`. Here's how I think the solution should (probably) look like:

```
unitAt: aPoint
    ^ map 
        at: aPoint
        ifAbsent: [ self error: 'The space is empty' ]
```

Called like this:

```
myPoint := 1@2.
unitOfPoint := myObject unitAt: myPoint.
```